# GNU make question

Tags: makefile

```
AR  = ar
LIBMISC = libapue_db.a
COMM_OBJ   = db.o
RANLIB     = ranlib

all: ${LIBMISC} libapue_db.so.1 t4

libapue_db.a:   ${COMM_OBJ}
        ${AR} rv ${LIBMISC} ${COMM_OBJ}
        ${RANLIB} ${LIBMISC}
```

What does `ar rv` mean? I just know ar is a command and rv is an option.
What is ranlib? 
thank u.

Comment: Please use a descriptive title for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I recommend checking man pages first for this sort of information.

`ranlib` is a program that builds the index in a static library archive.  The line with `${AR}` says add to `${LIBMISC}` all of the objects that `${COMM_OBJ}` expands to, replacing (`r`) any existing objects with that name.  The `v` option asks for verbose output.

Comment: thank you Dava. Yes,I checked GNU make manual but so much information.Cannot pick it up. Thank you!.